# How to use InputForm for printed and output expressions in console mode

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, scripting, configuration

When I run *Mathematica* in console mode (`math.exe`/`wolfram.exe`) without a GUI frontend, then printed and output expressions are (apparently) formatted using `OutputForm` (pseudo-2D layout). What option can I set to format them with `InputForm` (ideally, without attaching visible "InputForm" marker to every output)?

I tried to do `$PrePrint = InputForm`, but it does not affect `Print`ed expressions. Also, it overrides `FullForm`, `MatrixForm` and others in expressions like `FullForm[...]`.

Comment: So unless it is another *Form it should be an InputForm, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:

```
$Post = ToString[#, FormatType -> InputForm] &;
```

But this does not affect `Print[]`. Of course, you can always define your own print function which does exactly what you want. That is what I recommend here.

Do something such as, for example:

```
print[x_] := Print[ToString[x, FormatType -> InputForm]];
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain, by which convoluted logic, Print[ FullForm[ expr ]] just doesn't work and print instead : `FullForm[ expr ]`... it make no sense to me !

Comment: @yota Please give an actual example. I just tried `Print[FullForm[x+y]]` and it outputted `Plus[x, y]` as expected.